# How to render ♀️, ♂️ this symbols while rendering the emojis?

Tags: javascript, unicode

I have an issue related to rendering these symbols in emojis(♀️, ♂️).  How can I remove these symbols. And I want to know about what these symbols are? please help me. below I'm attaching a screenshot for more info.[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Gbc.png)

```
emojiProcess= function(s) {
   try{
       s= s.replace(/[\u200b\u200c\u200d\ufeff]/g,"");
       var EmojiString = JSON.parse('{"message":"'+s+'"}');
       return EmojiString.message;
   }catch(err){
       return s;
   }
```

};

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!. Please elaborate more on what you mean by `handle`? what are your intentions and what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Try improve description of your problem. Provide code where are you so far. Put your question into translator to improve your english.

Comment: `And I want to know about what these symbols are?` -> women and men mate.

Comment: *"And I want to know about what these symbols are"* Female and male, respectively.

Comment: Show the (JavaScript) code producing that view.

Comment: added. This is for processing the unicodes.

Answer (score 0):

> How to render ♀️, ♂️ this symbols while rendering the emojis?

That's not a JavaScript or programming question at all. Displaying this conforming to the standard is the task the of the font rendering subsystem.

> How can I remove these symbols.

```
let female_runner = '\u1F3C3\u200d\u2640';
let gender_unspecific_runner = female_runner.replace('\u200d\u2640', '');
```

> And I want to know about what these symbols are?

See [UTS #51 §2.1.1](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/tr51-14.html#gender-neutral) and [L2/16­181 § Gender Alternates](https://www.unicode.org/L2/L2016/16181-gender-zwj-sequences.pdf#h.p50dena22l0b).